# Assembly Pushing address of array onto stack

Tags: assembly, stack

Seg Fault Help

Towards the beginning a program being called from c, I have

```
movl (%ebx, %ecx, wordsize), %esi
```

where

`ecx` is a counter from 0 to `num_items`, and `ebx` is an array of integers passed from c code function call

```
movl 8(%ebp), %ebx
```

At the `movl` for the `esi` register, there is a seg fault for every file. Any ideas as to why?

Thanks!

I should also add that this does not occur on the first iteration of knapsack, but the second iteration

I think it may have something to do with how i pushed the "new" array onto the stack

I have this to push that onto the stack:

```
push (%ebx, %ecx, wordsize)
```

again where `ecx` acts as i + 1 and wordsize = 4

What i want to push on the stack is this:

```
weights + i + 1
```

`ebx` is the weights array

Comment: Is the pointer to array of integers the only parameter passed to your function? Can you show the instructions between the start of your assembly function and `movl 8(%ebp), %ebx`?

Comment: Post your entire function, or better yet a minimal, complete, and verifiable example that replicates the problem.

Comment: Also, use a debugger to examine ebx and ecx at the time of the fault, then figure out why they got broken.

Comment: Thanks guys! I ended up figuring it out. In place of the movl instruction should have been leal instead